# Facebook Workplace PHP SDK Unknown path components

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook SDK return my Unknown path components but i use this sabe path for cURL and works.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{APP_ID}',
  'app_secret' => '{APP_SECRE}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v6.00',
]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{GROUP_ID}/members',
    '{ACCESS_TOKEN}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
?>
```

I tried several ways but same erros, search but same problem with other people, on cURL query this path works, but are 5K limitation.

Error:

```
Graph returned an error: Unknown path components: /{MY-GROUP-ID}/members
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: That is your real access token. Please remove it from this post and invalidate it before people do bad things with it.

And if that is your real app secret go and reset that one too

Comment: This exemple token

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/group/members:

> This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used.

You can not request a list of members any more.

> on cURL query this path works

You mean something like `https://www.facebook.com/groups/{group-id}/members/`?

Then you would not be using the API in the first place.

*Scraping* data this way is not allowed.